# Separating two parallel lines using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, line

I have two parallel lines, with a distance x between them. I need to split the line in two using arcpy

Example of the lines

[image]

Comment: split them in two evenly?

Comment: Yes, separate lines that are parallel

Comment: I think you want to explode the feature.  It appears you ave a single feature selected in the attribute table, but you have 2 lines showing as selected (i.e. multi part)

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to split the lines evenly, you can use the Feature Vertices to Points tool selecting MID, then when you have the midpoints of your lines, use the Split Line at Point tool.